# How to take a particular data using GREP?

Tags: grep

Command:

```
grep -oP '(?<=\"name\":\")[^"]*|(?<=\"title\":\")[^"]*' *.json >newjson
```

o/p getting as,

```
10XANY10G_1.json:chMax
10XANY10G_1.json:Max Frequency in GHz
10XANY10G_1.json:up
10XANY10G_1.json:UP
10XANY10G_1.json:down
10XANY10G_1.json:DOWN
10XANY10G_1.json:CapabilityList
10XANY10G_1.json:Capabilities
10XANY10G_1.json:encoding
10XANY10G_1.json:Encoding
```

expected o/p:

```
chMax:"Max Frequency in GHz",

up:"UP",

down:"DOWN",
```

contents of file:

```
{"card":{"cardName":"10AN10G","portSignalRates":["10AN10G-1-OTU2","10AN10G-1-OTU2E","10AN10G-1-TENGIGE","10AN10G-1-STM64"],"listOfPort":{"10AN10G-1-OTU2":{"portAid":"10AN10G-1-OTU2","signalType":"OTU2","tabNames":["PortDetails"],"requestType":{"PortDetails":"PTP"},"paramDetailsMap":{"PortDetails":[{"type":"dijit.form.TextBox","name":"signalType","title":"Signal Rate","id":"","options":[],"label":"","value":"OTU2","checked":"","enabled":"false","selected":""},{"type":"dijit.form.TextBox","name":"userLabel","title":"Description","id":"","options":[],"label":"","value":"","checked":"","enabled":"true","selected":""},{"type":"dijit.form.Select","name":"Frequency","title":"Transmit Frequency",}}}}}}
```

Comment: I do not see the data you like to get in the file. There are no `Max Frequency`, no `up` etc

Comment: Also, it makes almost no sense to parse JSON with grep.

Comment: expected o/p from above file:
signalType:"Signal Rate",

userLabel:"Description",

Frequecy:"Transmit Frequency",

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this,

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=\"name\":\")[^"]*|(?<=\"title\":)[^,]*' file
signalType
"Signal Rate"
userLabel
"Description"
Frequency
"Transmit Frequency"
```

To get the desired output

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=\"name\":\")[^"]*|(?<=\"title\":)[^,]*' file | paste -d: - -
signalType:"Signal Rate"
userLabel:"Description"
Frequency:"Transmit Frequency"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is that you are ORing the two groups with `|` try removing the `|` and  you will get closer to what you are looking for but you may have to add a term to skip any intervening tags for cases where `name` and `title` are not **immediately** after each other, then you might have to get clever to deal with the case that has an entry with a name but no title.

As said grep is **not** the best tool for parsing json there are numerous others - personally I would suggest using python and the json library to load your file then output the tags that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `gnu awk` (due to RS) version to extract data:

```
awk -F\" '/title/ {print $3":"$7}' RS='name' file
signalType:Signal Rate
userLabel:Description
Frequency:Transmit Frequency
```